# $G$-invariant non-degenerate form

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group acting on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

Suppose $V$ is inner product space with inner product $\langle -, -\rangle$, which may not be $G$-invariant.

Then the new inner product $\langle -, - \rangle_1$ defined by $\langle a,b\rangle_1=\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g\in G} \langle g.a, g.b\rangle$  becomes $G$-invariant.

My question is simple:

> if we take $F$ to be a field of characteristic not dividing $|G|$, and $\langle -, -\rangle$ is a non-degenenrate bilinear form on $V$, can the above argument work to obtain a $G$-invariant non-degenerate bilinear form on $V$?

(I think the answer is negative, but I was not able to find any reference. If it is already posted, please show me reference; I will remove my question.)

Comment: In case $F=\mathbb R$ this follows from the fact that $\langle a,a\rangle>0$, for $a\neq0$.  So I don't see how to make this work in other fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F=\mathbb{F}_7=\mathbb{Z}/(7)$; $V=\mathbb{F}_7$ as a $1$-dimensional vector space over $F$; $G$ be the cyclic group of order $3$ generated by $4$ with the multiplication action; and $\langle a,b\rangle=ab$.

$\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is nondegenerate: if $x\neq0$, then $\langle x,x^{-1}\rangle=1$.  But \begin{align*}
\langle a,b\rangle_1&=\frac{\langle a,b\rangle+\langle 4a,4b\rangle+\langle 2a,2b\rangle}{3} \\
&=5ab(1+2+4) \\
&=0
\end{align*} which shows that $V$ is null.

Lastly, I suspect positive-characteristic representation theory motivates this question.   In that case, the counterexample above has limited utility: whenever $\mathrm{char}(F)\nmid|G|$, representations are semisimple.

*Why?*  Even though the bilinear form you asked about degenerates, we only need it for the projection operator used in Maschke's theorem, and that is always a well-defined projection.